# Grouping events by year, month and then listing for each - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL table containing a listing of events that I am trying to display like so (not exact formatting):

**2011**

***January***

- Jan Event 1
- Jan Event 2
- Jan Event 3

**2012**

***March***

- Mar Event 1
- Mar Event 2

I was finally able to accomplish this using the PHP below but I **know** that there has to be a better way. As you will see, there are two nested `for each` statements. The `dateStart` column is a `DATE`.

```
$fetchEvents = $contentDB->query("SELECT id, title, description, dateStart, dateEnd, timeStart, timeEnd, 
YEAR(dateStart) AS year, MONTH(dateStart) AS month, MONTHNAME(dateStart) AS monthName
 FROM events_general ORDER BY dateStart");
while ($event = $fetchEvents->fetch())
{
    $title = $event['title'];
    $description = $event['description'];
    $dateStart = $event['dateStart'];
    $month = $event['monthName'];
    $year = $event['year'];
    $events[$year][$month][] = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'description' => $description,
        'dateStart' => $dateStart);
}
foreach ($events as $year => $month)
{
    echo "<p><strong>$year</strong>\n";
    foreach ($month as $monthListing => $eventListing)
    {
        echo "
        <p>$monthListing</p>\n
        <div class=\"accordion\">\n
        ";
        foreach ($eventListing as $event)
        {
            $title = $event['title'];
            $description = $event['description'];
            $dateStart = $event['dateStart'];
            echo "
            <h3><a href=\"#\">$title - $dateStart</a></h3>\n
            <div>\n
            $description \n
            </div>\n
            ";
        }
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a better way? What do you think is wrong with the way you've done it?

Comment: Do you think this way would work well with lots and lots of listings, not get bogged down? I have not worked with arrays much in this capacity but I seem to recall receiving an error in the past when I attempted something similar with over a hundred rows

Comment: This method will work fine even with "lots and lots of listings". Iterating over arrays like this is very fast.

Comment: You might get a problem if you have hundreds and hundreds of listings all with a lot of data as you might hit memory problems but in that case I doubt your users will want everything on one page anyway. I actually think your original code is better than the answer. For one, it splits the db/model code from the display/view code which will make it easier to manipulate in the future.

Comment: @liquorvicar - I am inclined to agree with you although, strictly speaking, this manipulation is display logic.

Comment: I think that I might just limit the number of results and only display events starting at the current date, using this code. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it in a single iteration but you will need to fiddle with where to put the closing `</div>` for the accordion -

```
$fetchEvents = $contentDB->query("SELECT id, title, description, dateStart, dateEnd, timeStart, timeEnd, 
YEAR(dateStart) AS year, MONTH(dateStart) AS month, MONTHNAME(dateStart) AS monthName
 FROM events_general ORDER BY dateStart");

$prevYear = '';
$prevMonth = '';

while ($event = $fetchEvents->fetch())
{
    $title = $event['title'];
    $description = $event['description'];
    $dateStart = $event['dateStart'];
    $month = $event['monthName'];
    $year = $event['year'];

    if ($year <> $prevYear) {
        // if a new year we definitely need to close the previous accordion div
        // unless it's the first iteration
        if ($prevMonth) {
            echo '</div><!-- close accordion div -->';
        }
        echo "<p><strong>$year</strong>\n";
    }
    if ($year <> $prevYear || $month <> $prevMonth) {
        // if new month but not new year close accordion
        if ($year == $prevYear) {
            echo '</div><!-- close accordion div -->';
        }
        echo "<p>$monthListing</p>\n";
        echo "<div class=\"accordion\">\n";
    }

    echo "<h3><a href=\"#\">$title - $dateStart</a></h3>\n<div>\n$description \n</div>\n";

    $prevYear = $year;
    $prevMonth = $month;
}
// add final closing div here
echo '</div><!-- close accordion div -->';
```

Comment: This works great but after extensive fiddling I can't seem to figure out how to work in the accordion DIVs... any ideas??

Comment: I really want to accept this solution but just cannot figure out a way to close the DIV without knowing which is the last event listing, such is the case with an array. If anyone could give me a pointer here, I would GREATLY appreciate it. I like how clean this solution is.

Comment: I have added the closing divs and comments.

Comment: Based on the comments from my question, I may end up sticking with what I started out with but only listing events greater or equal to the current date and then limiting them. But this works for sure and I really appreciate your help. Had a major brain fart with those closing DIVs, thanks for adding that. :)

Comment: Went with your solution, easy to read and I feel a little better without having so many arrays going on. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query SLIGHTLY modified.  I have an inner query that just grabs the year, month and last event date per year/month.  Then, by joining on that, I added an IF() check that if the date start matches that of the prequery "MaxPerMthYr", then set a flag to 1, otherwise, leave it as zero.  This might not work perfectly if you have multiple events on the same date.  If that is the case, another modification would need to be done, but IS doable to guarantee the correct entry.  The rest of your PHP code should work, but now you'll have the flag you were looking for.

```
SELECT 
      id, 
      title, 
      description, 
      dateStart, 
      dateEnd, 
      timeStart, 
      timeEnd, 
      YEAR(dateStart) AS year, 
      MONTH(dateStart) AS month, 
      MONTHNAME(dateStart) AS monthName,
      if( dateStart = MaxPerMthYr.LastDatePerGroup, 1, 0 ) as LastEntryPerGroup
    FROM 
       events_general,
          JOIN ( select YEAR(dateStart) AS perYear, 
                        MONTH(dateStart) AS perMonth, 
                        max( dateStart ) as LastDatePerGroup
                    from
                       events_general 
                    group by
                       YEAR(dateStart) AS perYear, 
                       MONTH(dateStart) AS perMonth ) MaxPerMthYr
           ON Year( Events_General.dateStart ) = MaxPerMthYr.perYear
             AND Month( Events_General.dateStart ) = MaxPerMthYr.perMonth
    ORDER BY 
       dateStart
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Reminded me just how much I need to improve my MySQL knowledge. I haven't tried to implement this yet (wife says it's time for bed, boo) but I will give it a shot.